# Convert CGPoint to Lat Long

Tags: mkmapview, latitude-longitude

I have a CGPoint where I need to convert it to lat long.

```
CGPoint centerOfMap = CGPointMake(mapView.frame.size.width/2,mapView.frame.size.heigh/2);
CGPoint topMidOfMap = CGPointMake(centerOfMap.x, centerOfMap.y-200); //Step 1
//Now get difference of longitude and latitude
CLLocationCoordinate2D centerOfMapCoord = [mapView convertPoint:centerOfMap toCoordinateFromView:mapView];   //Step 2
CLLocationCoordinate2D topMidOfMapCoord = [mapView convertPoint:topMidOfMap toCoordinateFromView:mapView];   //Step 2
```

I could not get the accurate lat long for the CGPoint.  Any pointers?

Comment: This is not related to Xcode.

Comment: When you say that it's not accurate, what do you mean? There is simple typo of `height`, but I'm sure that was introduced just in the process of composing/editing this question. I might replace your integer values with `CGFloat` (e.g. `2.0f` instead of `2`; won't make a difference here, though). And if I wanted the top center of the map, I might use `CGPointMake(centerOfMap.x, 0.0f)` instead of `CGPointMake(centerOfMap.x, centerOfMap.y-200)`. But other than that, this looks fine.